# Looking for a Pdf Printer to use in a Docx -> Pdf Conversion Service

Tags: c#, pdf, service, printing

I'm not sure if this is possible but as I was looking for a way to convert docx -> pdf serverside (Aspose is a bit expensive), I wondered if I could do this by printing my document to a Pdf Printer.

Altho, I would need a decent one then, as it shouldn't show dialogs when trying to print ofc.

Does anyone know if:

- This is possible
- There exists such a printer which can be easily used in a WCF Service

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`pdfcreator`](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator).

> PDFCreator is a free tool to create PDF files from nearly any Windows application.
>
> Key Features:
>
> - Create PDFs from any program that is able to print
>
> ...
>
> - Terminal Server: PDFCreator also runs on Terminal Servers without problems

If you can read DOCX content and print from your `WCF` service, the [`pdfcreator`](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator) printer driver will generate PDF from anything.